# In Swift, how can you traverse the class inheritance of an object?

Tags: class, inheritance, swift

I'm getting an object back from a method, and it is of a class I don't know, but I'd like to know what the superclasses are. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: pure Swift? no possible now. ObjC class? you can play with [runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Thank. That's annoying though. I would have thought they'd get that reflexion stuff in early to help with debugging.

Comment: Where/when are you getting it back? In the debugger, in the playground, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Traverse the tree by calling `superclass()` on the returned object and all of its parents. However, if your Swift class doesn't ultimately extend `NSObject`, then you're out of luck.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/superclass